# Disable gpg-agent

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, gnupg

How can I disable gpg-agent? I don't wish to have any service retaining passwords and want to enter them every time.

I recall disabling this service once before, but I'm not having any luck on the newer distribution.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:-

```
cat ~/sensitive_archive.tgz | gpg2 --passphrase-fd 0 --pinentry-mode loopback -c  > sensitive_archive.tgz.gpg
```

Note that you do not get the password prompt - you just type the password, and press enter (not ^Z or ^D - just enter).

I had already killed the agent process - not sure if that was necessary.

Comment: UPDATE: the above didn't exactly work - it's the right commandline options, but you can't do that with input pipe data.